# How to store a url in variable after onclick event?

Tags: url, variables, onclick, store

For example, in this piece of code:

```
<a href="www.some.html" onclick="...">www.some.html</a>
```

What I have write instead of three dots if I want to store the url (www.some.html) in variable (var MyURL) after click on link?

Answer (score 2):

When you click that link (and the onclick won't stop the default action) you will go to the link in href.

So to just store the link write this:

```
<a href="http://www.some.html" onclick="var a=this.href;return false">www.some.html</a>
```

the "return false" piece will stop the default action and prevent the browser from going to the url and you have a variable "a" with the value = "www.some.html"...

Answer (score 1):

the variable you want is just `this.href` - you can test it by setting your onclick to `alert(this.href)`. Note that the anchor will work better with a full URL, ie http://www.some.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use jquery

change link to...

```
<a href="www.some.html" id="myurl">www.some.html</a>
```

Then in jquery

```
$("#myurl").click(function(){
   //set var
   var MyURL = $(this).text();
});
```